# What methods exist for taking a European vehicle from the continental countries to Iceland?

Tags: europe, automobiles, iceland

Hopefully straightforward; as a European citizen in possession of a full driving license and legal vehicle; how can one take that vehicle (or motorbike) to Iceland?

Assume that any departure point in Europe is cost-effective to reach/use.

Comment: Well spotted.  Vote to close @CMaster

Comment: Credut hsa to go to @markmayo . I was suprised to see it had been asked before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Smyril Line](http://www.smyrilline.com/) operates a car ferry between Hirtshals (Denmark) and Seyðisfjörður (Iceland), via Tórshavn (Faroe Islands), generally making one trip per week.